# RPC and MessageQueues in node.js

Tags: node.js, message-queue, rpc, nowjs-sockets

What are the good use cases for using RPC over MQ ? If a node process wants to talk to a java program, can we use RabbitMQ ? What are the other alternatives ? 
what nowjs or dNode does that can not be done with socket.io ? 
There are many modules in node.js on either RPC or MQ.. Do they all cater to some specific need ?

### EDIT:

What I am looking for ?

1. How do you do a RPC style of full duplex communication between browser/client and server? I think the answer would be socket.io or nowjs or dNode.. Please add if there are more.
2. How does your node process talk to other processes in a heterogeneous system ? This might be necessary if you want to offload some of your CPU bound task to other processes... For example between node.js process and a Java process. There can be 3 different ways of doing that. Which one is suitable for what ?

   i. publish-subscribe

   ii. request-response

   iii. push-pull
3. When would you use xmpp and not rabbitMQ ?

Comment: It would help if you specified exactly what you are trying to do. Also, you are asking so many questions that it would more beneficial to split this up into multiple questions. I can tell you are talking about both communication between node processes, but it also looks like you are talking about connecting with clients?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, [NowJS](http://nowjs.com/) or [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) are good choices.
2. redis pub sub might work for you, as would using rabbit. Depends on your use-case.
3. I don't think xmpp and rabbit are comparable? rabbit is for messaging, xmpp is a chat protocol (like what google chat uses, I think).

/fyi #node.js IRC welcomes you: http://bit.ly/nodeIRC